# Is GROUP_CONCAT() Max Length on Function or Query?

Tags: mysql, sql

In the following two queries

Is `GROUP_CONCAT()` works on function only:

`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(~[1024]~), GROUP_CONCAT(~[1024]~)`

---

Or is it limited for `1024` record per query?

`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(~[512]~), GROUP_CONCAT(~[512]~)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum length for `group_concat()` is for the function call itself.  So two calls to `group_concat()` would each have their own intermediate strings with the same maximum length.

You can override it by setting the appropriate system parameter.